# Connecting two different op-amp circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

I have designed a circuit using an OP amp, 9V battery, and resistors to power up an LED when a thermistors resistance is lowered. (Pictured left on the image).

I am also interested in using another op-amp in the same design that will oscillate a different load. The image attached shows my progress, but I am unable to get the output of the 2nd op-amp to oscillate. My main question is how to connect my first circuit (that turns an LED on when the thermistor detects heat), to the second part that will oscillate the load using another op-amp and capacitor.

The resistor that is 69k in this image is my actual NTC thermistor, so when it is idle (no heat), the first LED is off.
[image]

[image: no]

This image shows the 2nd op-amp working. (V-out of the op-amp has an oscillating square wave)

Comment: Show your corrected circuit by editing your question.

Comment: I have added the image. What I'm thinking of is using the v-out of the 1st op-amp somehow, so that it doesn't disturb the first LED, but it allows for the 2nd op-amp to work as an oscillator to blink another LED.

Answer (score 0):

The second op-amp is not working because you have no bias resistor on the (+) input, so it 'locks' up.

Add a 1N4148 or 1N4007 diode from the output of the first op-amp through a 10K resistor, to the (+) input of the second op-amp, so when the LED is ON, the second op-amp should start working. The band on the diode should point to the second op-amp.

The diode is to prevent the second op-amp from running constantly, unless that is what you want.

Also, the LED on the second op-amp has no path to ground through a resistor, like your first op-amp does. 500 ohms is ok. You can increase your bias resistors on the first op-amp by a factor of ten, to extend battery life.

Comment: Apologies, but I made the oscillator in the simulation program and the oscillations are working as seen in this image: (the top right blue node shows the square wave) https://i.imgur.com/qGk2EvF.png I'm just stumped on how to connect these two.

Comment: Ok, that is much better. Still I would connect them as suggested if op-amp B is slave to op-amp A. It depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Normally such a connection would frequency modulate the second op-amp. If you want to gate it on and off that would take some more parts.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have solved the problem and made the circuit work. I did this by connecting the Vout of the first 4556AD op-amp to the Vs+ on the RC oscillator op-amp that has a frequency of 47 Hz. \begin{equation}
Frequency = \frac{1}{2\pi RC}
\end{equation}

When the 100k NTC thermistor gets heat applied, the Vout goes up to 9V from -9V, we have the LED turning on with somewhere around ~14mA, and the Vout is also connected to Vs+ on the RC op-amp, which begins the capacitors discharging/charging, and therefore the frequency occurs at the speaker.